# Java lambda SortId inside map operator

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following method, and I want to sort the list of courses of my user object, but I'm getting a compilation error:

```java
public UserDTO getUserById(Long id) {
  return userRepository.findById(id).map(user -> {
    UserDTO userDTO = userMapper.mapUserDTO(user);

    // This line is not working. I want to sort the list of courses.
    //userDTO.getListOfcourses().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(CourseDTO::getSortingNumber));

    return userDTO;
  }).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFound(String.format("User with id %s not found", id)));
}
```

This is the compilation error:

> The method `sort(Comparator.comparingInt(CourseDTO::getSortingNumber))` is undefined for the type `Set<CourseDTO>`

Comment: Please add the compilation error to the question.

Comment: @user16320675 it was just an oversight ;)

Comment: `Set` is not sorted and so does not have a `sort()` method (neither `sorted()` as commented out)

Comment: You need to convert the set to a list, before you can sort it.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl thanks the sorting is working . could you explain please why sorted not working with Set ?

Comment: @James I added a response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By its definition, a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) is *an abstract data type that can store unique values, without any particular order*. They are always unordered, because they are designed for fast-access. This is why they are not sortable.

If your courses come back as a `Set` from the database, you will need to convert them to a `List` to sort them.

```java
private static class UserMapper {
    public UserDTO mapUserDTO(User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            return null;
        }
        UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
        dto.setName(user.getName());
        // Sort when mapping...
        dto.setCourseList(user.getCourses().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Course::getName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return dto;
    }
}
```

### Full example

I mocked out all the repository and mapper stuff below.

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserService {
    private static final Map<Long, User> userLookup;

    static {
        // Add a default user as ID=1
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1L);
        user.setName("John Doe");
        Set<Course> courseSet = new HashSet<>();
        courseSet.add(new Course("CMSC100", "Bits and Bytes of Computer and Information Sciences"));
        courseSet.add(new Course("CMSC106", "Introduction to C Programming"));
        courseSet.add(new Course("CMSC133", "Object Oriented Programming I Beyond Fundamentals"));
        courseSet.add(new Course("CMSC250", "Discrete Structures"));
        user.setCourses(courseSet);
        userLookup = Collections.singletonMap(1L, user);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        try {
            UserDTO dto = userService.getUserById(1L);
            System.out.println(dto);
        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepositoryImpl();
    private UserMapper userMapper = new UserMapper();

    public UserDTO getUserById(Long id) throws UserNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findById(id).map(user -> {
            UserDTO userDTO = userMapper.mapUserDTO(user);
            return userDTO;
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(String.format("User with id %s not found", id)));
    }

    private static class UserMapper {
        public UserDTO mapUserDTO(User user) {
            if (user == null) {
                return null;
            }
            UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
            dto.setName(user.getName());
            // Sort when mapping...
            dto.setCourseList(user.getCourses().stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Course::getName))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            return dto;
        }
    }

    private static class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
        @Override
        public Optional<User> findById(Long id) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(userLookup.get(id));
        }
    }

    private static class UserDTO {
        private String name;
        private List<Course> courseList;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Course> getCourseList() {
            return courseList;
        }

        public void setCourseList(List<Course> courseList) {
            this.courseList = courseList;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[User={name=%s,courseList=%s}]", name, courseList);
        }
    }

    private static class Course {
        private String id;
        private String name;

        public Course(String id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[Course={id=%s,name=%s}]", id, name);
        }
    }

    private static class User {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private Set<Course> courses;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Set<Course> getCourses() {
            return courses;
        }

        public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
            this.courses = courses;
        }
    }

    private static interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {
        // See: UserRepositoryImpl
    }

    private static class UserNotFoundException extends Exception {
        public UserNotFoundException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    private static interface Repository<ENTITY, ID_TYPE> {
        Optional<ENTITY> findById(ID_TYPE id);
    }
}
```

### Output

> [User={name=John Doe,courseList=[[Course={id=CMSC100,name=Bits and Bytes of Computer and Information Sciences}], [Course={id=CMSC250,name=Discrete Structures}], [Course={id=CMSC106,name=Introduction to C Programming}], [Course={id=CMSC133,name=Object Oriented Programming I Beyond Fundamentals}]]}]